# How to add custom checkout field in user details mail template

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks, actions

I need to add custom field from my checkout page to email templates.
I already added custom input at checkout page and it shows up in mails but it shows up after products table and I would like it to show up in customer details. I can't find right hook to place it there. Code for my custom field:

```
// Hook in
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields)
{

  //New input
  $fields['billing']['OIB'] = array(
    'label'     => __('OIB', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('OIB', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
  );

  return $fields;
}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
  if (!empty($_POST['OIB'])) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'OIB', sanitize_text_field($_POST['OIB']));
  }
}


/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order)
{
  echo '<p><strong>' . __('OIB') . ':</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'OIB', true) . '</p>';
}


/* To use: 
1. Add this snippet to your theme's functions.php file
2. Change the meta key names in the snippet
3. Create a custom field in the order post - e.g. key = "OIB" value = 134852145798
4. When next updating the status, or during any other event which emails the user, they will see this field in their email
*/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_order_meta_keys($keys)
{
  $keys[] = 'OIB'; // This will look for a custom field called 'OIB' and add it to emails
  return $keys;
}

//Micanje Checkout polja
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'bbloomer_move_checkout_email_field', 10, 1);

function bbloomer_move_checkout_email_field($address_fields)
{
  $address_fields['billing_email']['priority'] = 25;
  $address_fields['OIB']['priority'] = 26;
  $address_fields['billing_phone']['priority'] = 27;
  $address_fields['billing_country']['priority'] = 28;
  return $address_fields;
}

// Custom validacija za OIB
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_OIB');
function custom_validate_OIB()
{
  $is_correct = preg_match('/^[0-9]{11}$/', $_POST['OIB']);
  if ($_POST['OIB'] && !$is_correct) {
    wc_add_notice(__('OIB se sastoji od <strong>11 brojki</strong>.'), 'error');
  }
}
```

I use NP Quote Request plugin which has it's own email templates.
I think that one of these hooks at the bottom of email template php file controls customer details.

```
do_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text);

do_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text);

do_action('woocommerce_email_confirmation_messages', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text);

do_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email);


try {
    do_action('woocommerce_email_footer');
} catch (Exception $ex) { }
```

Any help on which hook I should target or what I should do would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use woocommerce_email_customer_details.

```
function email_order_user_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
   $meta = get_post_meta($order->ID, 'OIB');
   if($meta){
       /*** whatever format you like here ***/
       echo '<tr>' . $meta '</tr>';
   }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'email_order_user_meta', 30, 3 );
```